# Creating a tooltip on hover in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I made a tooltip which appears when I hover on an element, and shows the full name of the product, `productName`.

```
<div
  className="product-select-info"
  onMouseEnter={e => productNameHandleHover(e)}
  onMouseLeave={productNameHandleNoHover}
>
  {productName}
  <div
    className="tooltip"
    style={{
      display: isTooltipShown ? "block" : "none",
      top: mouseLocation.y,
      left: mouseLocation.x,
    }}
  >
    {productName}
  </div>
</div>
```

And here are my handlers:

```
const productNameHandleHover = (event: any): void => {
  setmouseLocation({
    x: event.pageX,
    y: event.pageY,
  });
  setisTooltipShown(true);
};

const productNameHandleNoHover = (): void => {
  setisTooltipShown(false);
};
```

My problem is, I want to only show the tooltip after like 0.5 seconds. Currently, the tooltip appears as soon as the mouse goes over the div. How do I achieve this? I tried using `setTimeout` but I was just running into issues with that.

Comment: Do you have `lodash` as dependency?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz negative

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: what issues are you running into with setTimeout? That should work in this case

Comment: @Prasanna When the user moves the mouse away in those 0.5 seconds, my state fails to update correctly, and it sometimes gets stuck as `true`, and then the tooltip just remains on the screen..

Answer (score 2):

It is good to use css transitions as ritaj has mentioned in the comments.

But if you absolutely want javascript implementation, Whenever you are hovering over your element, set a class variable to be true.

```
const productNameHandleHover = (event: any): void => {
  this.hovering = true;
  ...
}
```

and set it false whenever it is not.

```
const productNameHandleNoHover = (): void => {
  this.hovering = false;
  setisTooltipShown(false);
};
```

And when you actually set your tooltip check if your class variable is set or not.

```
const productNameHandleHover = (event: any): void => {
  this.hovering = true;
  setmouseLocation({
    x: event.pageX,
    y: event.pageY,
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.hovering) {
      setisTooltipShown(true);
    }
  }, 500)
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-elion-sk216?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is a codesandbox that does what you need.

But you can already see the amount of effort you have to put in. So coming back to the original point. Using css transitions is a better option